# QML: How to add children to a base component's child instead of the root object of the component?

Tags: qml, qqmlcomponent

I have a base component named MyChart.qml like this

```
Item {
    id: root
    
    ChartView {
        id: myChartView
    }
    
    RowLayout {
        id: myToolbar
        }
    }
}
```

So it's basically a chart with a toolbar underneath it. I inherit this component in another component like this:

```
MyChart {
    *List of Children*
}
```

Here, how can I add the *List of Children* to *myToolbar* instead of *root* of the MyChart component?

Comment: Aswering my own question, You need to define each father as a property alias, and then you can add children to the data list by appending new QML components with "push" method (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) OR you can give it totally new values using "alias.data: [Object 1 {}, Object 2{}]" syntax, where alias is the property alias of the target qml object that you defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every item has the property `data` which is used as default property when you add an object inside another. Default property mean if you don't specify any property is assumed to be that one.

eg: `States` has `default property states: []`, so you can do

```
States {
   State{},
   State{}
}
```

beacause they all refer to that default property.
So, about your example it's enough to expose the default property of the component you want to be the direct father of your component

*MyChart.qml*

```
Item {
   id: root
   
   default property alias data: myToolbar.data
   
   ChartView {
      id: myChartView
   }
   
   RowLayout {
      id: myToolbar
   }
}
```

Now any child coponent you use will be added directly inside the rowlayout

```
MyChart {
    Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100; color:"red"}
    Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100; color:"skyblue"}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem for one Father. Is there a method to add children to more than 1 Father?

Comment: @PunittoMoe you should place your component inside a Component and then multiple loader which load the same component. Obviously each loader will have a copy of the component, not the same.